# Setting InitialViewController in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I want my app to check if user is logged in or not. I have two storyboards, one is for 3.5inch screens and one is for 4.0inch screens. But, the problem I'm having is that if users are logged in, I don't want it to display the LoginViewController which is the initialViewController in my StoryBoards and the HomeViewController which is the View you see after Login In.

Below is my **application didFinishLaunchingwithOptions**

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"u_id.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dico = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

if ([dico objectForKey:@"u_id"]) {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];

    CGSize iosDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;


    if (iosDeviceScreenSize.height == 480) {
        //Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file name
        UIStoryboard *iphone4 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4:4S:3Gs" bundle:nil];

        //homeView *view = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
        //UINavigationController *navcontrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view];

        //Instatiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iphone4 instantiateInitialViewController];

        //Instantiate a UIWIndow object and initialize it with the screen size
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        //Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the
        self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;
        //[self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[homeView class]];

        //Set the window object to be the key window and show it
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    if (iosDeviceScreenSize.height == 568) {
        //iPhone5 and all other 4Inch screens
        //Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named
        UIStoryboard *iphone5 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iphone5 instantiateInitialViewController];
        //homeView *view = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
        //UINavigationController *navcontrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view];

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
} else {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];

    CGSize iosDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;


    if (iosDeviceScreenSize.height == 480) {
        //Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file name
        UIStoryboard *iphone4 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4:4S:3Gs" bundle:nil];

        //Instatiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iphone4 instantiateInitialViewController];

        //Instantiate a UIWIndow object and initialize it with the screen size
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        //Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the
        self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;
        //[self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[homeView class]];
        //Set the window object to be the key window and show it
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    if (iosDeviceScreenSize.height == 568) {
        //iPhone5 and all other 4Inch screens
        //Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named
        UIStoryboard *iphone5 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iphone5 instantiateInitialViewController];
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}



return YES;
 }
```

Is it possible to set my HomeView as the View being displayed if user is already logged in and not the LoginView instead.

Comment: You have the same code at if-else branches. Read the documentation of `rootViewController` to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, they are the same code cause I don't know how to make the particular view I want as the rootView. So, I just left the code as I did it and I set the initialViewController manually in Storyboard @A-Live

Comment: If your goal is to select the right view, view controller is commonly used for that. Of course you can add a view as a window subview, but it isn't recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose which view controller to instantiate first and use a different storyboard method (`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`:) to fetch it...

```
CGSize iosDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
NSString *storyboardName = (iosDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)? @"iPhone4:4S:3Gs" : @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: storyboardName bundle:nil];

BOOL isUserLoggedIn = [dico[@"u_id"] boolValue];  // note the modern syntax for dictionary
NSString *vcId = (isUserLoggedIn)? @"LoggedInVCId" : @"NotLoggedInVCId";

// here's the punch line...
UIViewController *initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:vcId];
```

Also note, by using a string variable for `storyboardName` and `vcId`, compress the code and improve readability.

Comment: Sorry, the @"LoggedInVCId" : @"NotLoggedInVCId", would be replaced with my own defined VCIdentifire right?

Comment: This is the error i got   **Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?**  and the **BOOL isUserLoggedIn** is returning a warning of incompatible pointer to integer conversion initialization

Comment: Ohw, I've solved it. I've to set a view as Initial in storyboard to do that, Hommie you the coolest..... but I've to do this also to remove the warning **NSString *value = dico[@"u_id"]; BOOL isUserLoggedIn = [value intValue]; // note the modern syntax for dictionary**

Comment: Gotcha.  Glad it worked.  Sorry about the warning, that was lazy coding by me.  Edited.